# htaccess - quitar ?param=

Tags: php, .htaccess

tengo esta URI: www.miurl.es/productos/producto/nombre?medidas=90x180

me gustaría conseguir mediante .htaccess tener este tipo de url: www.miurl.es/productos/producto/nombre/90x180 pero no consigo mediante htaccess hacerlo. He mirado algunas de las reglas para estos casos pero no me solucionan mucho.

este es el htaccess actual:

```
Options +FollowSymLinks
Options -Indexes

RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f


#RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !^/es/
#RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !^/index.php
#RewriteRule (.*) /es/ [R=301,L]

#RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
#RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f 
#RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !(.*).php

RewriteRule (.*) /index.php
RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING}  ^medidas=$ [NC]
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ $1? [R=301,L]

Options +FollowSymLinks -MultiViews
RewriteEngine on
```

Alguna sugerencia???

Comment: Lo que quieres son **urls amigables**. Puedes hacer una búsqueda en el sitio que ya hay varios hilos abiertos sobre el tema. Saludos.

Comment: Gracias, miraré de nuevo, hasta ahora no me ha valido nada de lo que he encontrado. Saludos

Comment: Lo que veo es que puedes intentar generar así www.miurl.es/productos/producto/nombre/?90x180, dado que es un parámetro, pero no entiendo como lo leerías si no tienes el nombre del parámetro?,

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Buenas Héktor aqui te dejo como se haría:

Antes de nada esto tienes que hacerlo desde un servidor ya sea con un hosting web o local como xampp o wampp y tener activado el `mod_rewrite` para que funcione.

**Es importante que en este caso yo lo he hecho incluyendo el `.htacces` en la misma carpeta que nombre.php por lo tanto tendrías que hacerlo igual o en caso de querer ponerlo en la carpeta padre cambiar la ruta.**

```
# Activar RewriteEngine    
Options -MultiViews
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME}.php -f

# Reescribir la URL solicitada
# Entrada: nombre/medidas/ (ejemplo: nombre/23x34)
# Salida: nombre.php?medidas=23x34
RewriteRule ^nombre/([a-zA-Z0-9_-]+)$  ./nombre.php?medidas=$1 [L]
```

Lo he testeado y funciona a la perfección cualquier problema me pones un comentario.

Un saludo!

Comment: Gracias DSGDSR, no me funciona, supongo que algo estaré haciendo mal :(;
de todas formas, las entradas y salidas están invertidas, quizás me expresé mal, las correctas son:

#Entrada: nombre.php?medidas=23x34
#Salida: nombre/medidas/ (ejemplo: nombre/23x34)


y el "nombre" varía dependiendo del nombre del producto. 
Te agradezco tu tiempo e interés, gracias!!!

Comment: Ah perdona, lo del nombre no lo sabía pues no lo especificaste si quieres podría editarlo y la entrada y salida es correcto la entrada es mediante la url que tu accedes y la salida el redireccionamiento. Si conociera más sobre la estructura podría ponerlo a funcionar aún asi tengo una demo en la que esta corriendo por si quieres probarlo.

Comment: Sería genial poder probarlo :)